# Create PDFs inside a one specific folder

Tags: python, pdf, directory

In my code I first create a folder:

```
if not os.path.exists("my_folder"):
  os.mkdir("my_folder")
```

After my script makes multiple pdf`s. However, I would like the pdfs to all to end up inside that specific folder. I have tried:

```
pdf=PDF()
with open(os.path.join("my_folder", pdf), 'w') as pdf:
   pdf.add_page()
```

But, I get this Error TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - you are re-assigning `pdf` variable.
First you initialise it here:

`pdf=PDF()`

then here:

`with open(os.path.join("my_folder", pdf), 'w') as pdf:`

another thing - in `os.path.join("my_folder", pdf)` you are trying to join string with pdf instance. What does PDF() return? A string?

Overall code should look something like this:

```
pdf=PDF()
pdf.add_page()
with open(os.path.join('my_folder', 'pdf_file.pdf'), 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(pdf)
```

Comment: Thank you, PDF() return a class further up in the script with class PDF(FPDF). So when I changed the code I got the error: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not PDF. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try changing 'w' into 'wb'